# Generate 8 coordinates between a start coordinate and end coordinate

Tags: java, coordinates

Well, I have two coordinates (the red circles)
[image: Coordinates]

And I want to generate all these greens. and I know I'm moving wrong

I'm using the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class classA {

    static final int startX = 52760;
    static final int startY = 72440;
    static final int endX = 52520;
    static final int endY = 71896;
    static final List<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        calculate(startX, startY, endX, endY);

        coordinates.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void calculate(int _startX, int _startY, int _endX, int _endY) 
    {

        final int _x = (_startX + _endX) / 2;
        final int _y = (_startY + _endY) / 2;

        coordinates.add(_x + "," + _y);

        if (coordinates.size() != 8)
            calculate(startX, startY, _x, _y);
    }
}
```

I can understand that the code will calculate the start values from the 'next' end values (which are the center) but I can't configure it

the output is

[image: wrong]

how I supposed to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you dividing by 2 each time?  (Or in fact, why is 2 involved at all here?)

Comment: This is more of a mathematical question, instead of dividing by 2 you should calculate distance between those 2 points, then you put point on 1/8 of that distance, next on 2/8 of distance etc.

Comment: And why is recursion involved? This can easily done with a loop that adds 1/9th of the distance between start and end each time. (Why 1/9th and not 1/8th? Google off-by-one-error)

Comment: @FilipRistic the distance in this case is 594 considering the following code is correct   
(int) Math.sqrt((endX - startX) * (endX - startX) + (endY - startY) * (endY - startY))

But how I can get the coordinate of the 1/8th of this 594 for example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: Just for the record : a certain percentage of the population is color blind. Interestingly enough, especially males have red green difficulties. Surprisingly enough again, the majority of your readers here might be male. Long story short : don't use red and green colors when presenting content to a large number of unknown people. I absolutely cannot see any difference between all the slightly green dots you put up. Rather use colors that give less trouble. Or use different symbols such as plus and asterisk chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

In each step you are actually dividing the distance into two halfs:

```
final int _x = (_startX + _endX) / 2;
final int _y = (_startY + _endY) / 2;
```

That is also the exact reason why you see the first point in the middle and the next in the center of *(start, middle)* and so on.

---

### Solution

What you want to achieve is called [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

You need to divide the distance into `(8 + 1) = 9` parts of equal size (8 parts in between, 9 points in total). You do so by using

```
(end - start) / 9
```

Afterwards you repeatedly add this to `start` and receive all points. Or alternatively (for more precision) use multiplication as

```
start + i * ((end - start) / 9)
```

to receive the `i`-th new point.

Also you should not use **integer division** since it is always rounded downwards. For a precise result you should convert to `double`, then compute the result and finally convert back to `int` in order to display the values.

---

### Code

As code this may look like:

```
private static void calculate(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    int amount = 8;

    // Compute the distance to each point
    double wholeDistanceX = endX - startX;
    double distanceX = wholeDistanceX / (amount + 1);

    double wholeDistanceY = endY - startY;
    double distanceY = wholeDistanceY / (amount + 1);

    // Add all new points
    for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        // Compute current point
        double currentX = startX + i * distanceX;
        double currentY = startY + i * distanceY;

        // Create the point
        coordinates.add((int) currentX + "," + (int) currentY);
    }
}
```

Note that in Java you usually don't use `_` in front of variables.

---

### Illustration

Here's a quick image I just drew which should help to understand the equations:

[image: illustration]

You see the first and last point are located at `start` and `end`. The distance is `end - start`. The distance divided by `9` is as long as the distance from the first point to the second. The sixth point is thus located at

```
start + 6 * ((end - start) / 9)
```

Comment: As a slight improvement - use multiplication rather than incremental addition.  The latter can incur cumulative precision issues.

Comment: Thank you @OliverCharlesworth ! I completely understand how it works now! It is working perfect :)